# How to set up proxy reverse with wordpress

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I have a wordpress site running on http://www.testdomain.com

now I want to change it to http://productiondomain.com/Branch (I dont have control of this server at all. they set it up for us)

So right now when I visit http://productiondomain.com/Branch I get redirected to http://www.testdomain.com (which is not what I want. I want the url to remain http://productiondomain.com/Branch at all times.

Im pretty sure there is something I have to change in wordpress settings and in .htaccess file or in Apache config but Im really clueless in this area.

Please help.

Comment: Off-hand, I don't recall a default setting in the .htaccess file that includes the domain, but Wordpress does set the URL under Settings > General. For more information, see the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen)

Comment: Do you have access to phpmyadmin on productiondomain.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to ask the MySQL db administration at productiondomain.com to change some values in your wordpress database there.

Lets assume your wordpress database is called wordpress_db. In this case you have to ask him to run the following two queries (first change the options according to your needs)

```
UPDATE `wordpress_db`.`wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'http://productiondomain.com/Branch' WHERE `wp_options`.`option_name` = `siteurl`;
UPDATE `wordpress_db`.`wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'http://productiondomain.com/Branch' WHERE `wp_options`.`option_name` = `home`;
```

Alternatively you can add the following two lines to your wp-config.php file (again if you don't have access on the files of productiondomain.com, ask the admin there to do it for you)

```
define('WP_HOME','http://productiondomain.com/Branch');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://productiondomain.com/Branch');
```

There are also other ways, like adding two lines of code to your functions.php file, but one of the above two will do.

More information can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: Hmm.. I will keep control of the site. We are not planning on moving it anywhere. the site is currently hosted on justhost.com and I plan on keeping it there. its just that now we want to use a domain name that matches the rest of the company's sites.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You said that you moved the site to another server on which you don't have access to. I didn't say you should not keep control of the site. I just answered what you asked. Unless I didn't understand correctly.

Comment: We havent moved the hosting at all... but we do need the dns to be different... the site will still be stored on justhost.

Comment: Ok then I guess you have access to phpmyadmin for your wordpress database as well as your wordpress files (htdocs). So just do one of the above solutions and you'll be ok :-)

Comment: Ive tried both solutions but I keep getting http 310 too many redirects :s

Comment: Instead of going to http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/ try http://yourdomain.com/wp-login.php enter your username & password and most probably you will be redirected to wp-admin without the "too many redirects" error.

Comment: thats correct. the login page works just fine but after logging in the admin dashboard looks terrible. as if some css files are not being loaded properly... visiting index.php still triggers 301 too many redirects. :s ... Im really lost.

Comment: can you post your `wp-config.php` file please?

Comment: ok, ive figured out the problem. I needed to do what your answer sugested in addition to using this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/ ... dont know why but it now works. Thanks!